# WP, как поменять картинки на отдельных страницах?

Tags: wordpress

Есть хедер, ниже него находится блок с изображением. По центру блока кнопка-изображение. Заказчик хочет, чтобы он мог продублировать страницу, но что-то поменять на ней. Например, картинку кнопки или картинку блока. Это вроде бы можно сделать с помощью другого шаблона страницы, но заказчик вряд ли сможет сам это сделать.

Comment: Можно в зависимости от страницы менять контент.`if(){}` + `is_page()`

Comment: Не знаю, вряд ли он(заказчик) сможет это сделать, когда ему понадобится еще одна страница. Я предлагал ему сделать на Тильде(не любитель конструкторов, но там это намного проще реализовать), но ему тут Вордпресс подавай.

Comment: Через доп поля сделать можно, чтоб сам вводил нужную картинку и страницу в админке

Comment: Спасибо, хоть что-то. Не уверен что подойдет такой вариант, но все же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать шаблон страницы. Заказчик сможет выбирать его в админке, при создании новой страницы. И через доп. поля (например Advanced Custom Fields) сделать редактируемыми все необходимые элементы, в том числе и картинки.